# Encoding the right language in R

Tags: r, windows, csv

I have an Excel-CSV file which looks like this:

```
`! Ð’Ðž Ð’Ð›ÐÐ¡Ð¢Ð˜ ÐÐÐ’ÐÐ–Ð”Ð•ÐÐ˜Ð¯ (ÐŸÐ›ÐÐ¡Ð¢.)         D,0`,40
```

I try to encode the file in the right language.

If I read the file it looks like this:

```
read.csv("myfile.csv",
           stringsAsFactors = F)

`! Ð’Ðž Ð’Ð›ÐÐ¡Ð¢Ð˜ ÐÐÐ’ÐÐ–Ð”Ð•ÐÐ˜Ð¯ (ÐŸÐ›ÐÐ¡Ð¢.)         D,0`,40
```

If I try to encode the file using "UTF-8" it looks like this:

```
read.csv("myfile.csv",
               encoding = "UTF-8",
               stringsAsFactors = F)

! <U+0412><U+041E> <U+0412><U+041B><U+0410><U+0421><U+0422>
```

The goal is to get the encoding below (which I did in excel using 65001 unicode (utf-8))

```
!Якутск Орджоникидзе, 56 фран,0
```

If I try to encode the file using the format which a generated by excel using 65001 unicode (utf-8) I also get the same results as above.

```
structure(list(shop_name = c(" 56 Ñ„Ñ\200Ð°Ð½", ""), shop_id = c(0L, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("!Ð¯ÐºÑƒÑ‚Ñ\201Ðº ÐžÑ\200Ð´Ð¶Ð¾Ð½Ð¸ÐºÐ¸Ð´Ð·Ðµ", 
"!Ð¯ÐºÑƒÑ‚Ñ\201Ðº Ð¢Ð¦ \"Ð¦ÐµÐ½Ñ‚Ñ\200Ð°Ð»ÑŒÐ½Ñ‹Ð¹\" Ñ„Ñ\200Ð°Ð½,1"
))
```

Comment: It’s unclear what the file actually looks like but did you try setting the `encoding` parameter of `read.csv`?

Comment: Yes, I made an edit.

Comment: I can´t upload the csv. The `dput` is a result of `read.csv("myfile.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)`

Comment: What locale set on your computer?
If English, change locale to Russian and check output.
English locale don't show Cyrillic on my computer.